Cannot read property ‘IsAndroid’ of null / (react-native-sound)
I’m working on a React Native with version of 0.74.5 versión. Also I’m using react-native-sound library with the version 0.11.2
I pretty much have a blank project. I’m willing to play a mp3 file when pressing a TouchableOpacity component.
I’m receiving the following: ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'IsAndroid' of null, js engine: hermes on the console
My current App.tsx file look like this
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import Sound from 'react-native-sound'

export default function App() {
    Sound.setCategory('Playback')
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightblue', padding: 10, borderRadius: 10 }}
                onPress={() => {
                    console.log('test')
                }}
            >
                <Text>Test 1 - Sonido</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
})


react-native-sound seems to be unmaintained, the last update was 3 years ago. I would suggest using other package, you could try these:

react-native-track-player
You can use react-native-video and play audio only
You could also try expo packages: expo-av or expo-video


Take you so much. expo-av helped me correctly playing my audio!
